# como guardar checkbox seleccionados en array, con angular 6

Tags: javascript, array, checkbox, angular6

Tengo varios checkbox de la siguiente manera:

ts:

```
sectores = [{ sector: "Turismo" }, { sector: "Publico" }, { sector: "Privado" }, { sector: 'Taxis' },{sector:"Carga"},{sector:"Empresarial"}]
```

html:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-check custom-control-inline" *ngFor="let data of sectores;let i = index;">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="data[{{i}}]" [value]="data.sector" #inputSectores #inputSectores="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="settingUser.sectores[i]">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">{{data.sector}}</label>
                </div>

            </div>
```

el modelo o interface definido es el siguiente:

```
settingUser = {
  sectores:[null]
}
```

mi pregunta es  ¿como guardo en el array de sectores, los checbox que el usuario seleccione ?